# jQuery ajax call synchronous vs asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code with an ajax call.

```js
var value = 0;
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:3000',
dataType: "json",
type: 'POST',
data: formdata,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    value = data.data;
    console.log("Inside: " + value);

},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Error received");
}
});
console.log("Outside: " + value);
```

Executing, gives me

```
Outside: 0
Inside: 100
```

Is there anyway to make it run sequentially?

Comment: Just put your `console.log("Outside: "+value)` code inside the `success` callback, after the "Inside" thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, your question has nothing to do with Express or EJS. You want synchronous ajax in the browser, which is certainly possible. If you're using jQuery, you need to set the `async` property to `false`, as per this documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

It is, however, not recommended to do that, as explained there.